# How to get if user already liked the post on facebook while fetching post using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this graph API to fetch posts from Celebrity Page.
But I cannot get if User already liked the post or not.
I don't want to do new network call to check if user liked the post or not,since posts are going to show in listview and there would be 100's of network call in that way.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Spotlight.SherlynChopra/posts?fields=from.fields(picture,name),story,message,type,picture,link,source,object_id,comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.fields(from.fields(picture),message,created_time).summary(true)&access_token=[access_token]&limit=25
```

Comment: How did you fetch user like?